# Shifting underbrace with lualatex and unicode-math

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

Compiling this example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \symcal{L}_{\text{QED}} =
    - \underbrace{\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}}_\text{Photon}
    + \underbrace{\bar{\psi} (i \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m) \psi}_\text{Dirac}
    - \underbrace{eQ\bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu \psi A^\mu}_\text{WW}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

using lualatex from TeXLive 2016, the second `\underbrace`
is shifted to the left. This only seems to happen when the first thing in the `\underbrace` is `\bar`.

Even adding something ridiculous like `\hphantom{}` resolves the issue.

Only `\underbrace{\bar{\psi} (i \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m) \psi}_\text{Dirac}`:

[image: result1]

Adding an `\hphantom{}` before `\bar`

[image: result2]

---

A “more minimal” example, to be compiled with `luatex`

```
\input ifluatex.sty
\ifluatex
  \input luaotfload.sty
\fi

\font\mf="[latinmodern-math.otf]"
\textfont1=\mf \scriptfont1=\mf \scriptscriptfont1=\mf
\protected\def\underbrace#1{%
  \mathop{\Umathaccent bottom 7 1 "023DF\relax {#1}}\limits
}
\protected\def\hat{\Umathaccent fixed 7 1 "00302\relax}

$\underbrace{z+w}_y$\qquad$\underbrace{\hat{z}+w}_{y}$

\bye
```

[image]

If compiled with `xetex`, the output is

[image]

Changing the math font to `xits-math.otf` doesn't change the situation. With `Asana-Math.otf` the output is different:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This also happens with other accents such as `\hat`... it should be reported as a bug.

Comment: it's enough to use `{}` not sure yet whether it's a problem in unicode-math or luatex  (it's not mathtools, you get the same if you use `\[` and just load amstex for `\text`

Comment: It is `unicode-math` under `lualatex` that is the problem.  Minimal example: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
    \underbrace{ABCDEFGH}_P
    + \underbrace{\bar a IJKLMNOP}_D
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}`.  Under XeLaTeX it is fine.

Comment: @HenriMenke Indeed LuaLaTeX without `unicode-math` works fine.

Comment: The problem still seems to exist in TeX Live 2017.
Bug report for `unicode-math`: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/391

Comment: I've reported the bug to LuaTeX and will amend `unicode-math`.

Comment: This appears to be fixed with `unicode-math` version 0.8j, released 2018-01-07. Thanks, Will!

Comment: @egreg I just heard back from Hans; the workaround should no longer be needed in LuaTeX 1.07

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary workaround, you could add the empty brace group proposed by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323797/shifting-underbrace-with-lualatex-and-unicode-math#comment790719_323797) in the definition of the over- and underbraces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set:Nn \__um_set_math_overunder:Nnnn
 {
  \cs_gset_protected_nopar:Npx #1 ##1
   {
    \mathop
     { \__um_accent:nnn {#2} {#3} {#4} {{}{##1}} } % see the empty braces?
    \limits
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\[
  \symcal{L}_{\text{QED}} =
    - \underbrace{\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}}_\text{Photon}
    + \underbrace{\bar{\psi} (i \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m) \psi}_\text{Dirac}
    - \underbrace{eQ\bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu \psi A^\mu}_\text{WW}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better: `\__um_accent:nnn {#2} {#3} {#4} {{}{##1}}`, so the empty group will not interfere with the spacing at the beginning of the argument (for instance, if it's an operator).